# Error on replacing special characters with regex function

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am trying to replace the special characters and spaces in a string. I found online that a regex function is handy for this, but I can't seem to make it work.

When I try this the regex function throws an error "expected end of instruction":

```
Dim param = Regex.Replace("te  !,;stDD ", "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
```

When I try this the string is not changed but the regex function does pass:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]"
param = re.Replace("te  !,;stDD ", "")  'string doesn't change on result
```

Comment: RE.Global = True

Comment: this fixed it, thnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try this the regex function throws an error "expected end of instruction":
>
> ```
> Dim param = Regex.Replace("te  !,;stDD ", "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
> ```

The error is raised by the parser, not the regex method. In VBScript you cannot define a variable and assign a value to it in the same step. You MUST separate definition and assignment (if you want an explicit definition).

```
Dim param
param = Regex.Replace("te  !,;stDD ", "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
```

You can put both statements in one line by separating them with a colon, though:

```
Dim param : param = Regex.Replace("te  !,;stDD ", "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
```

Note, however, that there is no `Regex` class with a static `Replace()` method in VBScript, so you'd still be getting an error from `Regex.Replace()`.

You must instantiate a [`RegExp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab2dx62.aspx) object like you do in your second code snippet and use the `Replace()` method of that object.

> When I try this the string is not changed but the regex function does pass:
>
> ```
> Set re = New RegExp
> re.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]"
> param = re.Replace("te  !,;stDD ", "")   'string doesn't change on result
> ```

But the string *does* change. If you take a closer look at input and output you'll see:

```
"te  !,;stDD "      ← input string
"te !,;stDD "       ← output string
```

Your replacement operation removes the *first* character that is neither letter nor digit from the string. For your example string that is the first space. In order to remove *all* characters that aren't letters or digits you need to set the [`Global`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdte5kwf.aspx) property to `True`:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]"
re.Global  = True
param = re.Replace("te  !,;stDD ", "")
```

Comment: Thanks for the broad explanation and sollution!